I cant seem to figure out why all my data is getting deleted from the database, meanwhile i am only trying to delete only one. using mongoengine ODM
I am using the mongoengine ODM to build an API, And here is my isssue.  I have tried everything i can to make this endpoint to delete just one user, but its ends up deleting every user in the database. i set the username to be unique in the schema, but it keeps getting deleted.
@user_bp.route('/users/<username>', methods=['DELETE'])
def delete_user(username):
    try:
        user = User.objects(username=username).first()
        if not user:
            return jsonify({'message': 'User not found'}), 404

        user.delete()
        return jsonify({'message': 'User deleted successfully'}), 200
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'message': 'Failed to delete user', 'error': str(e)}), 500

That is my code, i am expecting it to delete just one, but it keeps deleting everything.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.
